org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider
org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider 

this has been deprecated in spring boot 3.x versions, but the replacement classes and methods has not been clear on what to use, only this one is mentioned in some articles.
another import
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcTags;

unable to get WebMvcTags under the upgraded spring

The documentation quite literally states what to replace it with.

Yes, but the methods related to the WebMvcTags are nowhere suggested

Because those don't matter anymore. The upgrade documentation (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes#micrometer-updates) is quite extensive how to upgrade.
